# angularjs external controller file results in error 'angular is not defined'

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I have following controller defined in an external file but when I try to run my node server I get 'angular is not defined' error.

vaultcontroller.js

```
angular.module('demoapp.vaultcontroller', [])
.controller('vaultcontroller', function($scope, appFactory){

    console.log("INSIDE APP CONTROLLER.");

    $("#success_holder").hide();
    $("#success_create").hide();
    $("#error_holder").hide();
    $("#error_query").hide();

    $scope.get_all_currencies_from_vault = function(){
        console.log("VAULT CONTROLLER IS CALLED -1 ");
        appFactory.queryAllTuna(function(data){
            var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                parseInt(data[i].Key);
                data[i].Record.Key = parseInt(data[i].Key);
                array.push(data[i].Record);
            }
            array.sort(function(a, b) {
                return parseFloat(a.Key) - parseFloat(b.Key);
            });
            $scope.all_tuna = array;
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.6.5",
    "angular-route": "1.6.5",
    "body-parser": "latest",
    "ejs": "latest",
    "express": "latest",
    "fabric-ca-client": "^1.0.2",
    "fabric-client": "^1.0.2",
    "grpc": "1.11.0",
    "morgan": "1.9.0"
},
```

This is the error trace:

```
angular.module('demoapp.vaultcontroller', [])
^

ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Project-code\demo-POC\demopoc\client\vaultcontroller.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Project-code\demo-POC\demopoc\client\routes.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

Here is my index.html imports

```
<!-- require jquery and bootstrap scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update-1**
Loading vaultcontroller

in app.js file, I did following.

```
.when('/vault', {
  templateUrl: 'vault.html',
  controller: 'vaultcontroller'
})
```

And the code for vaultcontroller is posted above.  Then I have done following in app.js

```
var demoapp = angular.module('application', ["ngRoute", "application.vaultcontroller"]);
```

And then imported the file in the index.html using script.

```
<!-- requiring the angular page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vaultcontroller.js"> </script>
```

If any more code required please let me know. New to angular

**Update-2 > Solution**
Ok, I got some help from @Aleksey Solovey  and as he suggested I installed a separate server http-server for delivering my static files, earlier my node server was delivering static files as well. I removed that part from the server.js and I didn't get any of the above errors, it started working. And I have now two URLs 
1. for static content > localhost:8080 
2. For API server (written in node, uses server.js for startup) > localhost:8000

Thank you for helping out.

Comment: I have added the script in index.js, it is already there in the html page.

Comment: Wait, do I need to add it in each and every page? I have one main index.html inside which I have a <div ng-view>, index.html contains all the files. Even the file of controller is also there.

Comment: how are you loading your `demoapp.vaultcontroller` module?

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope that is what you meant by loading of module.

Comment: I can't immediately see what's wrong, but a simple answer: your scripts cannot see `angular.js` (to find the reference for the `angular` variable), which means they are loaded before it. Does `vaultcontroller.js` script comes **after** `angular.js` script?

Comment: Yes, it does come after angular.js script. in fact after the app.js script. But does this apply to running the nodejs server? I mean scripts definitions are fine when you are running it in browser I get this error while running the node server.

Comment: Then I believe your code is not enough to replicate the issue. (There is only one typo, where you are injecting `application.vaultcontroller` but it's called `demoapp.vaultcontroller`)

Comment: What else do you need for code ?

Comment: Can the routes defined at one place only cause this problem? i.e. I have all of my routes defined in the app.js configuration and not in individual controller js files.

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem. I just don't know how node can break the scripts order

Comment: I tried one thing I opened the file in the browser directly wihtout using node server and it works :P but I want to run it using node only as I have APIs developed in node. I am using node version 8.11.1.

Comment: I think you need a local server, like [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or some bigger one

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? I am not getting what you are tyring to say.

Comment: Ok, I installed http-server and found that it is serving at port 8080 but how would I ask it to load a particular file ? i.e. my index.html is inside /project/client/index.html Is there a way I can map it directly to that file so that URL is like localhost:8080 in place of localhost:8080/client/#! & what changes I would require to run my nodejs backend ? As my APIs are still in nodejs but the server isn't running. due to some reasons.

Comment: Thanks for helping I figure it out :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Add the Blow

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Velu for answering I have imports already defined in the main index.html page.